# Prove that $ L': Im(L) \rightarrow V : x \mapsto L(x)$ is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and let $ L: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that the rank of $L$ is the same as the rank of $ L^2=L \circ L$.
Prove that the linear map $ L': Im(L) \rightarrow V : x \mapsto L(x)$ is injective.

I know it's injective when $ker(L')= {0}$. And I thought $Im(L)=V$ so  $ L':V \rightarrow V : x \mapsto L(x)$, I'm not sure if this is correct though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you some hints. What is the rank of a linear transformation? It's the dimension of the image space. So what does it mean when you say that rank of $L^{2}$ is same as rank of $L$? It basically says that $L$ when restricted to image of $L$ has the image of same rank as $L$ acting on $V$. However, image of $L^{2}$ is a subspace of image of $L$ and hence they are equal.

Your main fallacy seems to be that you think $Im(L) = V$.

Answer (score 1):

Directly: suppose $\;x\in\ker L'\;$ , then there exists $\;v\in V\;\;s.t.\;\;Lv=x\;$ since $\;x\in\text{Im}\,L\;$ , and:

$$0=L'x=L(Lv)=L^2v=Lv=x\implies x=0\implies \ker L'=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$L'$ is just $L$ restricted within the image of $L$. And as we know, $$
\mathrm{dim}(LV) =\mathrm{dim}\; \mathrm{ker}(L') +\mathrm{rank}(L')
$$ But by definition, $$
\mathrm{rank}(L') =\mathrm{rank}(L^2)
$$ And by assumption, $$
\mathrm{dim}(LV) =\mathrm{dim}(LLV) =\mathrm{rank}(L^2)
$$ Thus $$
\mathrm{dim}\; \mathrm{ker}(L') =0
$$ and $L'$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you! But where do you get that assumption from?

Comment: Well, isn't it you that supposed that $L$ and $L^2$ has the same rank ...?